# Is it possible to run .NET code compiled for .NET Core 2.2 at CoreCLR 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, coreclr

Is it possible to run c# code compiled for .NET Core 2 at CoreCLR 3? If it is possible, will I have any benefits like better garbage collection, mentioned in the .NET Core 3 [release announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/)?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to migrate the code to .Net Core 3. Microsoft provides migration documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30

Overall if your code is pretty basic there is likely not much for you to update.